# When I plot 2 columns one over the other, a different graph is plotted

Tags: python, plot, histogram

I have 2 columns from 2 np.arrays of the same size. When I plot the only the one I get this result:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(70,10))

for i,h in enumerate(clean_head):
    
    plt.subplot(1,6,i+1)
    #plt.hist(non_fire[:,i],alpha=.3)
    plt.hist(fire[:,i],alpha=.3)
    plt.title(clean_head[i])
    
   # plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: only one column plotted]

When I plot both I get this:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(70,10))

for i,h in enumerate(clean_head):
    
    plt.subplot(1,6,i+1)
    plt.hist(non_fire[:,i],alpha=.3)
    plt.hist(fire[:,i],alpha=.3)
    plt.title(clean_head[i])
    
   # plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: both columns plotted on the same histogram]

Where no one of the two histograms is the same with the initial. I dont understand which is the pink and which is the lightblue graph.

I have 16 more plots like that and I have the same problem with all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the second set of plots the blue histogram is for the "non-fire"-case and the orange one is for the "fire"-case. If you would plot a third histogram, it would be green. In general you can change the color of a given histogram using the parameter [color](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html).

The reason why your histograms change is that your arrays have different value ranges. You can fix this by explicitly giving bins the the function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(100)
b = np.random.rand(100)*2

bins = np.linspace(min(np.min(a), np.min(b)), max(np.max(a), np.max(b)), 10)

plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
plt.hist(a,alpha=.3, bins=bins)
#plt.hist(b,alpha=.3, bins=bins) #toggle this to see the effect
```

Also note that histogram function returns the list of bins that it uses.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this is really helpful thank you very much. trying to implement the bins assignment to my case I write:      bins = np.linspace(min(np.min(non_fire[:,i]), np.min(fire[:,i])), max(np.max(non_fire[:,i]), np.max(fire[:,i])), 10) but iget this error: TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Comment: What structures are your fire and non-fire objects (e.g. numpy array) and which datatype to the values have?