# Histogram Bins, TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python, histogram

I want to make my plots to have the same range to plot them in the same graph. So I needed to explicitly add bins as suggested by thomas here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55377604/7919440 . Both are numpy arrays.

My code is this:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(70,10))

for i,h in enumerate(clean_head):

    plt.subplot(1,6,i+1)
    a = non_fire[:,i]
    b = fire[:,i]

    bins = np.linspace(min(np.min(a), np.min(b)), max(np.max(a), np.max(b)), 10)
    plt.hist(a,alpha=.3,bins=bins)
    plt.hist(b,alpha=.3,bins=bins)
    plt.title(clean_head[i])
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Should I change the type somehow to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the problem was that I had to change my np.array's datatype to a flexible type with .astype(np.float) as shown below:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(70,10))

for i,h in enumerate(clean_head):

    plt.subplot(1,6,i+1)
    a = non_fire[:,i].astype(np.float)
    b = fire[:,i].astype(np.float)

    bins = np.linspace(min(np.min(a), np.min(b)), max(np.max(a), np.max(b)), 10)
    plt.hist(a,alpha=.3,bins=bins)
    plt.hist(b,alpha=.3,bins=bins)
    plt.title(clean_head[i])

   # plt.tight_layout()
```